# Have an image fly off the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I set it up so that the play image is not attached to the curtains, the red border?

So the play image can fly off the screen, so it goes past it's border.

https://jsfiddle.net/v8j26qxw/

It shouldn’t stay within the red border.

How it works is, when you click on the play image, it splits in half.

How do I set it up so that when the play image separates, it goes off the screen?

That is what I am trying to do.

The play image is staying within the red border, I want it to go outside and off the screen.

The issue is, the play image staying inside the red border, I don't want it to.

**I don't want the play image being hidden.**

Not this:
[image: Not this]

It should be doing **the below** instead.

I want the play image being fully visible going outside the red border.

Preferably a way that doesn't use **z-index**.

What I am looking for:
[image: What I am looking for]

```js
const cover = document.querySelector(".split-wrap");
(function manageCurtain() {
  "use strict";

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
  }

  const cover = document.querySelectorAll('.jacketa');
  cover.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', coverClickHandler)
  });
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  "use strict";
  
    let player = null;
  
  const tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100); // percent
  }
  let hasShuffled = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    const shufflePlaylist = true;

    if (!hasShuffled) {
      player.setShuffle(shufflePlaylist);
      player.playVideoAt(0);
      hasShuffled = true;
    }
  }

  function addPlayer(video) {

    const playlist = "M7lc1UVf-VE";

    new YT.Player(video, {

      width: 640,
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 0,
        controls: 1,
        loop: 1,
        rel: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3,
        cc_load_policy: 0,
        fs: 0,
        disablekb: 1,
        playlist
      },
      events: {
        "onReady": onPlayerReady,
        "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
 
  };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    const wrapper = cover.parentElement ;
    const frameContainer = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
    videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer);
}

(function iife() {
  "use strict";

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const wrapper = evt.currentTarget;
    show(wrapper);
  }

  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1500/1500) no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtain-wrapper {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
}

.curtain-ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;

  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.curtain {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent;
}

.slide-wrap:before,
.slide-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 5s linear;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1500/1500) no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slide-wrap:before {
  left: 0;
}

.slide-wrap:after {
  right: 0;
}

.slide .slide-wrap::before {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide .slide-wrap::after {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.jacketa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #130e85;
  border: 3px solid #f91f6e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #f9066bf7;
  display: block !important;
}

.j1 .jacketa {
  left: 30px;
}

.j2 .jacketa {
  right: 30px;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 75.4px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .back {
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .front {
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  animation: draw 20s infinite linear, flicker-1 2s linear 2s infinite both;
}

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flicker-1 {

  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  41.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  42% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  47.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  48% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.split-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.j1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.j2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.curtain.slide .j1 {
  left: -500%;
}

.curtain.slide .j2 {
  left: 500%;
}

.wrap iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.wrap,
.jacket {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="tcell">
    <div class="curtain-wrapper">
      <div class="curtain-ratio-keeper">
        <div class="curtain">

          <div class="video-wrapper">
            <div class="video-ratio-keeper">

              <div class="wrap">
                <div class="video video-frame"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="slide-wrap"></div>

          <div class="split-wrap">
            <div class="j1">
              <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
                <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
                  <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
                  <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
                  <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
                </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="j2">
              <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
                <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
                  <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
                  <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
                  <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
                </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Yes I will............

Comment: The play image is staying within the red border, I want it to go outside and off the screen. https://i.imgur.com/rS9iYs6.png The issue is, the play image staying inside the red border.

Comment: @csshtmljavascript14578 So you want the play button to fadeout instead of dragging along the curtains?

Comment: No, not fade out, I want you to be able to see the play image go beyond the red border and off the screen.

Comment: The button is goes out of the screen for me: https://imgur.com/a/PFMCWgv

Comment: Off your monitor screen? It goes beyond the red border and off your monitor screen?

Comment: Show me the play image on the outside of the red border. Can you do that?

Comment: Yes, I make a short video: https://streamable.com/e2cnkt

Comment: It doesn't do this https://i.imgur.com/4QIdD7z.png

Comment: I added an image to the topic.

Comment: Why do you want to uglify your project?

Comment: Ya for me also its working the play symbol fully get get hidden by sliding both sides

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, have the play image go outside the red border.

Comment: I don't want the play image being hidden.

Comment: I want the play image being fully visible going outside the red border.

Comment: Is anyone able to solve this issue of the split play image so it is able to go past the red border? Is this something that is hard to do?

Answer (score 1):

Need move up your `div class="split-wrap"`, like that. Because in `div class="curtain"` is a parent and you use `overflow: hidden`. All child  out of scope will hidden.  After that when you put it above `div class="curtain"` you can add some split animation.

```js
const cover = document.querySelector(".split-wrap");
const button = document.querySelector('.split-wrap'); // this line

(function manageCurtain() {
  "use strict";

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
    
    button.querySelector('.j1').classList.add('move-left'); // this line
    button.querySelector('.j2').classList.add('move-right'); // this line
    
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
  }

  const cover = document.querySelectorAll('.jacketa');
  cover.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', coverClickHandler)
  });
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  "use strict";
  
    let player = null;
  
  const tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100); // percent
  }
  let hasShuffled = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    const shufflePlaylist = true;

    if (!hasShuffled) {
      player.setShuffle(shufflePlaylist);
      player.playVideoAt(0);
      hasShuffled = true;
    }
  }

  function addPlayer(video) {

    const playlist = "M7lc1UVf-VE";

    new YT.Player(video, {

      width: 640,
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 0,
        controls: 1,
        loop: 1,
        rel: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3,
        cc_load_policy: 0,
        fs: 0,
        disablekb: 1,
        playlist
      },
      events: {
        "onReady": onPlayerReady,
        "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function play() {
    player.playVideo();
  }
  return {
    addPlayer,
    play
  };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    const wrapper = cover.parentElement ;
    const frameContainer = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
    videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer);
}

(function iife() {
  "use strict";

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.parentElement;
    show(wrapper);
    videoPlayer.play();
  }

  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1500/1500) no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtain-wrapper {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;

}

.curtain-ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;

  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.curtain {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent;

}

.slide-wrap:before,
.slide-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 5s linear;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1500/1500) no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.slide-wrap:before {
  left: 0;
}
.slide-wrap:after {
  right: 0;
}
.slide .slide-wrap::before {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.slide .slide-wrap::after {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

.jacketa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #130e85;
  border: 3px solid #f91f6e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #f9066bf7;
  display: block !important;
}

.j1 .jacketa {
  left: 30px;
}

.j2 .jacketa {
  right: 30px;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 75.4px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .back {
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .front {
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  animation: draw 20s infinite linear, flicker-1 2s linear 2s infinite both;
}

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flicker-1 {

  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  41.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  42% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  47.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  48% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


.split-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 10s ease;
  z-index: 100; /* This line */
}

.j1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 10s ease;
  /* transform: translate(-350px) /* This line */
}

.j2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 10s ease;
/*   transform: translate(350px) This line */
}

.curtain.slide .j1 {
 left: -500%;
}

.curtain.slide .j2 {
  left: 500%;
}


.wrap iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
}


.wrap,
.jacket {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);

}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

/* movement class */
.move-right {
  transform: translate(350px);
}
.move-left {
  transform: translate(-350px);
}
```

```html
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="tcell">
      <div class="curtain-wrapper">
        <div class="curtain-ratio-keeper">
          <div class="split-wrap">
            <div class="j1">
              <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
                <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
                  <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
                  <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
                  <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
                </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="j2">
              <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
                <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
                  <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
                  <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
                  <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
                </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="curtain">
            <div class="video-wrapper">
              <div class="video-ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrap">
                  <div class="video video-frame"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="slide-wrap"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle of it working in the code?

Comment: What has to be changed in the rest of the code? https://jsfiddle.net/skqubrL1/

Comment: Add in css .split-wrap  parameter z-index: 100;

Comment: look like this: .split-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 10s ease;
  z-index: 100;
}

Comment: When you click on it it the play image is not splitting apart. https://jsfiddle.net/0eL1mon4/

Comment: I don't think this is workable. In my code the play image splits apart, this one it doesn't.

Comment: You need recode in JS your function for this animation trigger. I'm added css properties and marked those.

Comment: @csshtmljavascript14578 You need to play with **z-index** options! Once succeeded perfectly for me but unfortunately I refreshed the page and I forgot what are changed in Chrome DevTools :(

Comment: How would it be done without using z-index options, is it possible?

Comment: I think no, because you can try to move the **split-wrap** out of **curtain-wrapper** but then the positioning is failed

Comment: @ЖнецЪ Only the red border and the backbround image visible! That is failed!

Comment: z-index needed for layers hierarchy. In your case you need play button above player and background.

Comment: Are you saying it is impossible to do?

Comment: How do you remove the overflow?

Comment: The overflow has to be hidden.

Comment: I did not remove overflow, just added z-index in "split-wrap" class, moved div class="split-wrap" above the class="curtain"that is all.

Comment: Can what I did here be improved? https://jsfiddle.net/j9va6ord/    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
    const slide = document.querySelector(".j1");
    slide.classList.add("move-left");
    const slide2 = document.querySelector(".j2");
    slide2.classList.add("move-right");
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
  }